# How to calculate fluid or air velocity and pressure field with boundary conditions?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics

If I have the simple equation for velocity field:

$$\frac{d\vec v}{dt}=(\vec v\nabla)v+\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{t}}=\rho{\nabla{p}},$$

it seems like I have to measure the density and pressure field to get the velocity field. Or if I want to get pressure field, I have to know velocity field and density field. In real world, we only get discrete data at some area.

How do people perform the calculation?

How do they confirm that the shape of a plane is good?

Comment: [Computational fluid dynamics (CFD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics)

Comment: On a side note: Your equation is dimensionally incorrect and I thing you are due a minus sign on the right hand side. i.e. you should have $-\frac{\nabla p}{\rho}$ on the RHS.

Comment: That equation (once you add a dot operation between the $\vec{v}$ and $\nabla$ and invert the density) is usually coupled with other equations. For compressible flows you will have the conservation of energy and mass, as well as a state equation for the fluid. For incompressible flows, you have the divergence free condition that allows you to solve for pressure (up to a constant) along with the velocity field.